# Android: How to make appbar like this?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've seen this in an application.

[image]

As you can see, the appbar is semi transparent and it's not a big deal but by scrolling down the page, it begins to Highlights more and more until it completely becomes non trasparent appbar, something like this :

[image]

**Question:** How can I make something like this ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@nullthemall/1-20f-behaviors-of-alpha-6f506c9cb6a7

Answer (score 3):

The action bar you mentioned is collapsed toolbar layout, it was currently available by using android design support library. Here are some guide on how to implement it into your application.

[Design Support Library (IV): Collapsing Toolbar Layout](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

[Handling Scrolls with CoordinatorLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)

[Toolbar Animation with Android Design Support Library](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/)

Official announcement: [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.my/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cor_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapseToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/event_image"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.6" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                android:theme="@style/MyCustomToolbarTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_white_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:rippleColor="?attr/colorControlHighlight" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , I tried  the code but I got these error : Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute 'contentScrim' in package ''
Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute 'expandedTitleMarginEnd' in package ''
Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute 'expandedTitleMarginStart' in package ''
Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_scrollFlags' in package ''
Error:(25) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_collapseMode' in package ''

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'    You need to add these dependencies to your gradle file